# Stream a display, transform it, and display it in a window?

Tags: swift, macos, avfoundation, core-graphics

I have a need for an app, and being a decent(I think) Swift developer, I thought I’d take a crack at it.

The gist of it is simple: I want to

1. Capture a display (CGDisplayStream?)
2. Flip the image vertically
3. Display the flipped stream in a window.

I’m just not sure where to start? Maybe CGDisplayStream or maybe AVFoundation? Does anyone have example code of how to accomplish capturing a display stream and displaying it in a window? Or even a guide of ‘use these classes/interfaces/apis’ to do this? I’ve github searched for CGDisplayStream.init and not really come up with any examples :(

I’m not asking anyone to write it for me, but I could use a: start here, use this, watch out for...

Here's the code I'm currently experimenting with. I *think?* I have steps 1 & 2 working, but it's hard to tell without #3...

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var displayStream: CGDisplayStream?
  let backgroundQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.app.queue",
                                      qos: .background,
                                      target: nil)
  var body: some View {
    VStack{
      MetalView()
      Text("Hello")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .onAppear{
          self.displayStream  = CGDisplayStream(dispatchQueueDisplay: 0, outputWidth: 100, outputHeight: 100,pixelFormat: Int32(k32BGRAPixelFormat), properties: nil, queue: backgroundQueue) { (status, code, iosurface, update) in
            
            switch(status){
            case .frameBlank:
              print("FrameBlank")
              break;
            case .frameIdle:
              print("FrameIdle")
              break;
            case .frameComplete:
              print("FrameComplete")
              var image = CIImage(ioSurface: iosurface!)
              image = image.transformed(by: CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1))
              break;
            case .stopped:
              print("Stopped")
              break;
            @unknown default:
              print("Unknown Error")
            }
            
            
          }
          
          displayStream?.start()
        }
        .onDisappear{
          displayStream?.stop()
          displayStream = nil
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I've created a mtkview NSViewRepresentable like this:

```swift
import MetalKit
import SwiftUI

struct MetalView: NSViewRepresentable {
  func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
  }
  
  func makeNSView(context: NSViewRepresentableContext<MetalView>) -> MTKView {
    let mtkView = MTKView()
    mtkView.delegate = context.coordinator
    mtkView.preferredFramesPerSecond = 60
    mtkView.enableSetNeedsDisplay = true
    if let metalDevice = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice() {
      mtkView.device = metalDevice
    }
    mtkView.framebufferOnly = false
    mtkView.clearColor = MTLClearColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0)
    mtkView.drawableSize = mtkView.frame.size
    mtkView.enableSetNeedsDisplay = true
    return mtkView
  }
  
  func updateNSView(_ nsView: MTKView, context: NSViewRepresentableContext<MetalView>) {
  }
  
  class Coordinator : NSObject, MTKViewDelegate {
    var parent: MetalView
    var metalDevice: MTLDevice!
    var metalCommandQueue: MTLCommandQueue!
    
    init(_ parent: MetalView) {
      self.parent = parent
      if let metalDevice = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice() {
        self.metalDevice = metalDevice
      }
      self.metalCommandQueue = metalDevice.makeCommandQueue()!
      super.init()
    }
    
    func mtkView(_ view: MTKView, drawableSizeWillChange size: CGSize) {
    }
    
    func draw(in view: MTKView) {
      guard let drawable = view.currentDrawable else {
        return
      }
      let commandBuffer = metalCommandQueue.makeCommandBuffer()
      let rpd = view.currentRenderPassDescriptor
      rpd?.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = MTLClearColorMake(0, 1, 0, 1)
      rpd?.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = .clear
      rpd?.colorAttachments[0].storeAction = .store
      let re = commandBuffer?.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: rpd!)
      re?.endEncoding()
      commandBuffer?.present(drawable)
      commandBuffer?.commit()
    }
  }
}
```

This is the first time I've ever done anything with metal, or core image and I'm feeling like i'm on shaky ground - understanding wise -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can do most of the work with Core Image:

1. The handler of the `CGDisplayStream` gives you an `IOSurface`. You can wrap that inside a `CIImage` with `CIImage(ioSurface:)`.
2. Apply any (or multiple) `CGAffineTransform` to the `CIImage` using `image.transformed(by:)`.
3. Use a `CIContext` to render the resulting image into an `MTKView`. Maybe you can get some inspiration from my example [here](https://github.com/frankschlegel/core-image-by-example/blob/main/Shared/PreviewView.swift).

Note: I'm not 100% sure if Core Image would properly retain the `IOSurface` for you when you wrap it in a `CIImage`. You should double-check if you still need to perform any of the actions described in the [handler documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgdisplaystreamframeavailablehandler).

Comment: Thank you so much. I think I actually got steps 1 and 2 working, but I'm ... totally confused about how to do #3. I'm going to post my code here, in a vain attempt that my hacked together bits are on the right path. Would you mind giving it a look see and pointing me in the right direction?

Comment: You still need a way to get the image rendered into the `MTKView`. Did you check out the example code I linked above?